# Is there a shortcut in Python for a long mess of nested for loops?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing a project for my free time just trying to generate big 12 character strings with characters in a linear order.

To do so I use a beast of 12 nested `for` loops.

```py
def linear():
    vocabulary = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase
    coupon = list("000000000000")
    count = 0
    for a in range(36):
        coupon[0] = vocabulary[a]
        for b in range(36):
            coupon[1] = vocabulary[b]
            for c in range(36):
                coupon[2] = vocabulary[c]
                for d in range(36):
                    coupon[3] = vocabulary[d]
                    for e in range(36):
                        coupon[4] = vocabulary[e]
                        for f in range(36):
                            coupon[5] = vocabulary[f]
                            for g in range(36):
                                coupon[6] = vocabulary[g]
                                for h in range(36):
                                    coupon[7] = vocabulary[h]
                                    for i in range(36):
                                        coupon[8] = vocabulary[i]
                                        for j in range(36):
                                            coupon[9] = vocabulary[j]
                                            for k in range(36):
                                                coupon[10] = vocabulary[k]
                                                for l in range(36):
                                                    coupon[11] = vocabulary[l]
                                                    count += 1
                                                    print(''.join(coupon), "  -  Attempt number: ", count)
```

It works as expected but I'm wondering if Python can amaze me once again with a prettier way that can still allow me to iterate each combination as it's being generated - because as others pointed out - 36^12 combinations is unrealistic.

Comment: look at the `itertools` module, should have something you can use :)

Comment: Of course, this means 36 ** 12 iteractions, and it would take a fe billion times the total lifetime of the universer running to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see:

```
import string, itertools
for a in itertools.product(string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=12):
    print(''.join(a))
```

But I wouldn't try to run this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't solve my problem by implementing it to work in the same manner as my original code, It's most likely my fault as I was being too blunt in asking the question, but I want to print each combination and this answer does not help me achieve any combination because as you pointed out, 36^12 is not realistic.

Comment: @Yuval I don't understand you want to print each combination but admit it's not realistic? In any case, I changed the code so that now it prints each combination immediately once it is computed.

Comment: that's just what I needed! I meant that I needed a way to deal with each combo right after it's calculated because **iterating over a list containing the combos is not realistic**.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools.combinations(iterable, r)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations
import string
vocabulary = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase
output = list(combinations(vocabulary, 12))
output = [('').join(x) for x in output]
```

However consider that there are `36^12` combinations possible ~ `4.7383813e+18`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't solve my problem by implementing it to work in the same manner as my original code, It's most likely my fault as I was being too blunt in asking the question, but I want to print each combination and this answer does not help me achieve any combination because as you pointed out, 36^12 is not realistic.

Comment: Never tried it bu frankly I highly doubt you could usefully print out  36^12 lines with python